# Is there a way to make this crossplatform?

Tags: linux, windows, c++11, time, cross-platform

Im trying to get rid of a platform dependent code.

This code gets a string formated by a mask ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") and convert it to std::tm struct and a std::time seconds.

I want to get rid of the need of preprocessor dependant blocks, as (imho) there must be a standard way of doing it in both platforms in the same way. 
strptime does not exists in windows, std::get_time does not exists(?) on linux (g++ c++11).

Is there any way to make this code crossplatform (windows/linux) without using a factory pattern or preprocessor dependant blocks?

```
KDATETIME& KDATETIME::operator= (const char* k)
{
std::string smask;
smask = (std::string)this->mask;
std::string sk;
sk=k;
tm.tm_isdst=-1;

#ifdef WINDOWS    <<---- THIS BLOCK 

std::istringstream ss(sk);
ss >> std::get_time(&tm, smask.c_str());

#else

strptime(sk.c_str(), smask.c_str(), &tm);

#endif          <<------

this->time = mktime(&tm);  // t is now your desired time_t
[...]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check OS with a preprocessor directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive)

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès thanks but no, the preprocessor directive is already known (is set by the crosscompiler) what I want to do, is to get RID of the need of a preprocessor directive to do something both systems should be able to do in a standard way (I suppose). I'll clarify the question.

Comment: Maybe `strftime()`?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès thank you, but strftime (format a tm struct into a string) does the opposite to strptime (fill a tm struct with the data from a string). As there is no strptime in windows, I had to use this approach. This is the only difference between windows and linux in this class, so my intention is to avoid having to split it in factory classes.

Comment: Oh sorry, you may try to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842369/time-t-to-string-back-and-forth-in-windows

Comment: i was looking for a standard way. In my humble experience, doing such a standard function myself leads to suffering.